# Problem with encrypting files in directory on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

I have tested the encryption part of the program and it works just fine for individual files, or even things like "file1,file2,file3" but it doesn't work with directories. The code looks fine to me, however when executing it gives me a segmentation fault.

It's supposed to encrypt files in directory and write them in the same directory with a new extension (old name + ".wbf") and decryption with extension removal upon the opposite. I'm only going to post the parts of code that deal with the files, the do_crypt function that works with individual files works just fine, and I think it's not the source of my problems.

```
    // PHP explode function

    vector<string> explode (string text, char separator)

    {

        vector<string> split;

        int last_trip = 0, pos = 0;

        text += separator;

        for (pos = 0; pos < text.size(); pos++)

        {

            if (text[pos] != separator)

            {

                // continue with iteration

            }

            else

            {

                split.push_back(text.substr(last_trip, pos - last_trip));

                last_trip = pos + 1;

            }

        }

        return split;

    };

    // LINUX -- directory listing function
    string LS (string dir)
    {
        DIR *dp;
        vector<string> files;
        struct dirent *dirp;
        if ((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) = NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error (" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
            //return errno;
        }
        while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
        {
            files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
        }
        closedir(dp);
        string explosive = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
        {
            explosive += files[i];
            if (i != (files.size() - 1)) { explosive += ','; } 
        }
        return 0;
    }

// various functions for encryption

int main (int argc, char* argv[])

{

    cout << "\t! ENCRYPTR -- File encryption utility written by WBlinder, 2010. !" << endl << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\t\tOPTIONS:" << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\t1\tCRYPT A FILE" << endl << "\t\t\t2\tDECRYPT A FILE" << endl << endl;

    cout << "choice > ";

    int opt;

    cin >> opt;

    string sin, sout;

    string dummy; getline(cin, dummy);

    /*cout << "input files > ";

    cout.clear(); cin.clear();

    getline(cin, sin);

    vector<string> fin = explode(sin, ',');

    cout << "output files > ";

    getline(cin, sout);

    vector <string> fout = explode(sout, ',');

    if (sin.size() != sout.size())

    {

        cout << "NO. INPUT FILES UNEQUAL NO. OUTPUT FILES" << endl;

        return 1;

    }*/
    string dir;
    cout << "dir > "; 
    getline (cin, dir);
    vector<string> input = explode(dir, ',');
    vector<string> output = input;
    switch (opt)
    {
        case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++)
            {
                output[i] = output[i] + ".wbf";
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++)
            {
                output[i] = output[i].substr(0, (output[i].size() - 4));
            }
            break;
    }

    cout << "password > ";

    getline(cin, key);

    cout << "N > ";

    cin >> N;

    cout << "(768 => fairly secure\t3072 => secure)\nextra rounds > ";

    cin >> drop;

    for (int brick = 0; brick < input.size(); brick++)

    {

        do_crypt(opt, dir + input[brick], dir + output[brick]);

    }

    /*string text;

    cout << "text to split: ";

    getline (cin, text);

    vector<string> tnt = explode(text, '.');

    for (int i = 0; i < tnt.size(); i++)

    {

        cout << i << ": " << tnt[i] << endl;

    }*/

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see where it segfaults?

Comment: I would but how ? I only have  experience with debugging C# not C++ and I'm on Ubuntu. gdb, or ?

Comment: To find the point of the segfault, you can launch your program in gdb (`gdb ./myapp`). In the gdb prompt, you start your program with the `run` command. If you need to pass arguments, list them after the `run`. When you program segfault, gdb will stop, and you can use `bt` to get the callstack, and `list` to get the currently executed line of code. Here is a gdb tutorial: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: Your sample code does not call the `LS` function even tough you suspect the crash to be in this function. It also contains lots of commented code. When posting, you should try to post the smallest example that illustrate your problem. Here, you could probably remove all the code, except the `LS` function, and the `main` could be reduced to `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { string files = LS("."); return 0; }`. This is sufficient to reproduce the crash on my computer.

Comment: Or if you prefer a GUI, you can use DDD (or another GUI frontend for gdb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is many problem in your `LS` function. First, you should make it directly return a `vector<string>` instead of packing the data in a `string` using a comma to separate value. This would save you a call to `explode` function, and would not break if the directory contains a filename with a comma in it (which is a valid name on Linux).

But the bigger problem (that is causing) your segfault is the `return 0` line. Since your function is declared to return a `string` object, and since `string` class has an implicit constructor from `const char*`, this is interpreted by the compiler as `return string(NULL)`. And when called with a `NULL` pointer this constructor raise a `logic_error` exception. As you didn't catch the exception, the C++ runtime call the `abort` function. This function cause a segfault by design in order to stop execution (and if enabled generate a coredump to allow post-morten debugging).

You should at least rewritte your `LS` function like that:

```
string LS (string dir)
{
    DIR *dp;
    vector<string> files;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    if ((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error (" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
        return string();
    }
    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
    }
    closedir(dp);
    string explosive = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
    {
        explosive += files[i];
        if (i != (files.size() - 1)) { explosive += ','; } 
    }
    return explosive;
}
```

Or better, change its signature to return a `vector<string>` and rewrite it like that:

```
vector<string> LS (string dir)
{
    DIR *dp;
    vector<string> files;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    if ((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) != NULL)
    {
        while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
        {
            files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
        }
        closedir(dp);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error (" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
    }
    return files;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's partially working now. The encrypt part of it is working perfectly but the decrypt not so much.

Answer (score 2):

`if ((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) = NULL)`

I think you mean `== NULL`

Comment: I also made one other modification   do_crypt(opt, dir + "/" + input[brick], dir + "/" + output[brick]); but still SEGFAULT.